# Adding to an ArrayList using input from GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I first created an arraylist in another part of the program, then used for loops to put it in the text area. Now, I want to take input from the text field, add that to the arraylist, and display the entire array, including the new element added. I tried using a for loop again, but when i click "add" while running, the program just freezes and nothing happens. Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

```
private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // Using a for loop to display unsorted list, sorting the list, then using a for loop again to display the sorted list 

    String strUnsortedList = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < strCDNames.size(); i++)  {
         strUnsortedList += strCDNames.get(i) + "\n";

    }

    Collections.sort(strCDNames);

    String strSortedList = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < strCDNames.size(); i++)  {
         strSortedList += strCDNames.get(i) + "\n";

    }
    txtOutput.setText("Unsorted Order: \n" + strUnsortedList + "\nSorted Order: \n" + strSortedList);



}                                          

private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String strAddedList = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < strCDNames.size(); i++)  {
          strAddedList += strCDNames.add(txtInputTitleArtist.getText());
    }
    txtOutput.setText(" " + strAddedList);
}
```

Comment: i wil always be less than strCDNames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < strCDNames.size(); i++)  {
    strAddedList += strCDNames.add(txtInputTitleArtist.getText());
}
```

This is an infinite loop. You keep adding to the list, which means that the list size will keep increasing. Hence `i` will **always** be lesser than `strCDNames.size()`.

Instead you can do something like this:

```
strCDNames.add(txtInputTitleArtist.getText());
String strAddedList = String.join(" ", strCDNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vivin is right. I just want to add that the arraylist add method returns a boolean (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-). So, in this case strAddedList wouldn't even be properly updated.